# List Accumulation with Append

Tags: python, list

I want to generate or return an append-accumulated list from a given list (or iterator). For a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, I would like to get, `[1]`, `[1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Like so:

```
>>> def my_accumulate(iterable):
...     grow = []
...     for each in iterable:
...         grow.append(each)
...         yield grow
...
>>> for x in my_accumulate(some_list):
...     print x  # or something more useful
...
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This works but is there an operation I could use with [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to facilitate this? (I'm on Python2 but the pure-python implementation/equivalent has been provided in the docs.)

Another problem I have with `my_accumulate` is that it doesn't work well with `list()`, it outputs the entire `some_list` for each element in the list:

```
>>> my_accumulate(some_list)
<generator object my_accumulate at 0x0000000002EC3A68>
>>> list(my_accumulate(some_list))
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

---

Option 1:

I wrote my own appending accumulator function to use with `itertools.accumulate` but considering the LoC and final useful-ness, it seems like a waste of effort, with `my_accumulate` being more useful, *(though may fail in case of empty iterables and consumes more memory since `grow` keeps growing)*:

```
>>> def app_acc(first, second):
...     if isinstance(first, list):
...        first.append(second)
...     else:
...        first = [first, second]
...     return first
...
>>> for x in accumulate(some_list, app_acc):
...     print x
...
1
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(accumulate(some_list, app_acc))  # same problem again with list
[1, [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

*(and the first returned elem is not a list, just a single item)*

---

Option 2: Figured it would be easier to just do incremental slicing but using the ugly iterate over list length method:

```
>>> for i in xrange(len(some_list)):   # the ugly iterate over list length method
...   print some_list[:i+1]
...
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to use `accumulate` is to make each item in the iterable a list with a single item and then the default function works as expected:

```
from itertools import accumulate
acc = accumulate([el] for el in range(1, 5))
res = list(acc)
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: And you can remove parentheses around the generator expression for extra prettiness: `accumulate([el] for el in range(1, 5))`

Comment: @vaultah yup... I originally had that because I was using operator.add as the function argument and then realised it was redundant and just happened to have forgotten to remove 'em :p

Comment: Yes, this is awesome because for lists `operator.add` (`+`) does `[1] + [2] = [1, 2]`, `[1, 2] + [3] = [1, 2, 3]` and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Also, any idea why my `my_accumulate` didn't work well with `list()` ?

Comment: @aneroid Because you return the reference to `grow` and `grow` is changed in every `yield` (`grow` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]` finally).  You can change `yield grow` to `yield grow[:]` to get the expected result.

Comment: @acw1668 Okay, that worked. Thanks. Forgot that since it's a reference to the list, what I'm getting in the final list is four references to the same list which has changed by the end  of the `yield`-ing loop.